# Format and Replace <TR> and <TD> within an ArrayList and get a formatted ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, html-parsing

Since I am unable to format the HTML formatting of the TD and TR(since StackOverflow.com has a auto-HTML formatter which is causing problem to write the exact code e.g. TD & TR), so kindly consider the following format for the proposed text:-

```
<tr>
   <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 13, 13, 13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 14, 14, 14</td>
</tr>
```

I have an ArrayList which is being populated from a Session variable:-
ArrayList ar3 = (ArrayList)Session["arr3"];

```
Session["arr3"] = "<tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 13, 13, 13</td> </tr><tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 14, 14, 14</td> </tr><tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 15, 15, 15</td> </tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 16, 16, 16</td> </tr>
```

All I want to do is to format this ArrayList(ar3) in such a way that I can have the individual records starting from starting TR & TD and ending at closing TR & TD, in another ArrayList(e.g. ResultArList). 

This ResultArList will be then used in an E-mail Relay and some plain-text Log(custom table created in DB).

The ResultArList  should have the records as:-

ResultArList[0]=FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 13, 13, 13
ResultArList[1]=FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 14, 14, 14
ResultArList[2]=FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 15, 15, 15
ResultArList[3]=FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 16, 16, 16

The quantity of these values in ArrayList ar3 are infinite, but the format of the above HTML is constant.

Please help me how to custom format my ArrayList and create a new formatted ArrayList.

Comment: Take a few minutes to learn how to format code.  Your question is unreadable.

Comment: You need to format your code as code so that it won't be rendered as HTML.  With what you've got there it's too mangled to even be readable.

Comment: You really shouldn't ever be using `ArrayList` in C#; you should be using the generic `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a regular expression to extract whatever is between the  tags; for example:

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=<td>).+?(?=</td>)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var text = "<tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 13, 13, 13</td> </tr><tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 14, 14, 14</td> </tr><tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 15, 15, 15</td> </tr> <td>FO Special Added (Comments, Part #, RFQ #) - 16, 16, 16</td> </tr>";
var matches = regex.Matches(text);

var results = matches.Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToList();
```